# Deploying Cairo contract using Protostar

Tags: starknet, cairo-lang

`protostar invoke --contract-address 0x041a78e741e5af2fec34b695679bc6891742439f7afb8484ecd7766661ad02bf --function "deployContract" --network testnet --account-address 0x0691622bBFD29e835bA4004e7425A4e9630840EbD11c5269DE51C16774585b16 --max-fee auto --inputs 3364682477454529426048922860407825503854228380792118216736163724255276409513 7 0 1 1`

I ran the command above, got the error in the screenshot[protostar error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGZF3.png)

I tried google but since this(cairo-lang) is this fairly new, google was not of big help, I want to deploy contract I wrote with cairo-lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to deploy a smart contract. Protostar has a newer version that exposes the command `protostar deploy` that makes use of the Universal Deployer Contract (UDC). Here's a [link to their docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/protostar/docs/tutorials/interacting-with-starknet/deploy) for deployment.